# How do I move the x-axis lable of an X-Y graph in LabVIEW?

Tags: graph, labview, axis-labels

I'm using LabVIEW 2013.
I have several X-Y graphs on which I need to change the text of the axis labels at run time. The X-axis labels seem to wander a little to the right every time I change them, this has gone so far that some have wandered off the graph area entirely and I can't see them any more.

I've tried various properties of the graph to no avail, even setting them to be the same as the ones from a fresh default x-y graph.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the position of the label:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'd actually tried that, but I'd assumed the coordinates were relative to the graph, not the front panel, so I didn't try any values large enough, and setting them to the same as a fresh graph didn't work because it wasn't directly above/below it.